# header constant on scroll

Tags: javascript, html

Html----included my content within

```
  <header1>
   ..............
 </header1>
```

JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var $header1 = $("header1"),
$clone = $header1.before($header1.clone().addClass("clone"));

 $(window).on("scroll", function() {
var fromTop = $("body").scrollTop();
$('body').toggleClass("down", (fromTop > 200));
});
});
</script>
```

Css

```
header1.clone {
position: fixed;
top: -120px;
transition: 0.1s top ease-in;
}

body.down header1.clone {
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 999;
 }
```

this works fine in google chrome but not in firefox...help me in this issue.....

Comment: Describe your problem in detail

Comment: header details and menu is in top of my page....i need my menu bar should come on top  while scrolling down and when i go back to top it should be as same as initial....  i used the above to clone that menu and display but its not compatible to all

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this using CSS like:

```
fixedCSS
{
position: fixed;
top:0; left:0;
width: 100%;
}
```

And apply this class using JQuery like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var $header1 = $("header1"),
$clone = $header1.before($header1.clone().addClass("clone"));

 $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
       $('.header1').addClass('fixedCSS');
    }
    else {
       $('.header1').removeClass('fixedCSS');
    }

});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your need a header that's always shown, so instead why not use CSS?

```
header {position:fixed;}
```

Comment: if i use like that mean,some issues arise as per my requirement.... ie ....I have included some transparency to the content ,as i scroll menu moves under that content...

Comment: Oh yes, that would indeed be an issue. Or, it can lead to a design update, which gives light to semi-translucent see-through panes for your top header. Now if this was an issue I had to contend with, I would, but I have no time to contemplate on this for you. Yet, I did at least try :)